# Merge item in array of object with the same ID on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is how the object look:

```js
let data = [
  {
    brandId: '12345',
    brand: 'Adidas',
    item: {
      name: 'Adidas 1',
      price: '200',
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: '12345',
    brand: 'Adidas',
    item: {
      name: 'Adidas 2',
      price: '230',
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: '7878',
    brand: 'Nike',
    item: {
      name: 'Nike 1',
      price: '305',
    },
  }
];
```

i want the `item` object will merge if the object have the same `brandID` :

```js
let data = [
  {
    brandId: '12345',
    brand: 'Adidas',
    item: [
      {
        name: 'Adidas 1',
        price: '200',
      },
      {
        name: 'Adidas 2',
        price: '230',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    brandId: '7878',
    brand: 'Nike',
    item: {
      name: 'Nike 2',
      price: '316',
    },
  },
];
```

is there any javascript syntax or method to do this ? and with an explanation will be very nice, Thank You

Comment: `item` shouldn't be an object or array; it should always be an array.

Comment: This type of structure should be discouraged, I'm not sure what kind of database you are using but you should try to filter and aggregate them properly directly in the query, running loops in your code to sort such structure is really not scalable as the input grows (your products array)...

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that your output is just a typo and name/price doesn't actually changes) You can use [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
let data = [
  {
    brandId: '12345',
    brand: 'Adidas',
    item: {
      name: 'Adidas 1',
      price: '200',
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: '12345',
    brand: 'Adidas',
    item: {
      name: 'Adidas 2',
      price: '230',
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: '7878',
    brand: 'Nike',
    item: {
      name: 'Nike 1',
      price: '305',
    },
  }
];

const mergedItems = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // check if current exist on the accumulator
  const exist = acc.find(brand => brand.brandId === curr.brandId);

  // if it does, add the item on it
  if (exist) {
    return acc.map((brand) => {
      if (brand.brandId === exist.brandId) {
        return {
           ...brand,
           item: brand.item.concat(curr.item),
        }
      }
    })
  }

  // if it doesnt, add it on accumulator, and make the item array
  return acc.concat({
    ...curr,
    item: [
      curr.item 
   ]
  })
})
```

(I wrote the code manually and not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
let data = [
  {
    brandId: "12345",
    brand: "Adidas",
    item: {
      name: "Adidas 1",
      price: "200",
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: "12345",
    brand: "Adidas",
    item: {
      name: "Adidas 2",
      price: "230",
    },
  },
  {
    brandId: "7878",
    brand: "Nike",
    item: {
      name: "Nike 1",
      price: "305",
    },
  },
];

const dict = new Map();
data.forEach((o) => {
  dict.get(o.brandId)
    ? dict.get(o.brandId).item.push(o.item)
    : dict.set(o.brandId, { ...o, item: [o.item] });
});

const result = [];
for (let [k, v] of dict) {
  v.item.length === 1 ? result.push({ ...v, item: v.item[0] }) : result.push(v);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```